# Delete entry of a variable conditional on existence of another - R

Tags: r

I'd like to eliminate the entries for Var3 if Var4 has an entry, using R.
Below, I provide a Stata-code leading to the desired outcome:

If Var4 is unequal to "NA", I'd like to change the entry for Var3 to "NA".

The df in R:

```
Var1 Var2    Var3     Var4 
 a    a      Yes       No
 b    c      No        Yes
 a    b      Yes      "NA"
 c    a      Yes      "NA"            
 b    b      No        Yes
```

Stata command:

```
If Var4 != "NA" -> drop Var3
```

Desired outcome:

```
Var1 Var2    Var3     Var4 
 a    a      "NA"      No
 b    c      "NA"      Yes
 a    b       Yes     "NA"
 c    a       Yes     "NA"            
 b    b      "NA"      Yes
```

What I tried until now, but didn't work out:

```
test <- if(df$Var4 != is.na()) {
      test <- df[df$Var3] <- NA
      }
```

Based on my df I would like to apply an equivalent to the Stata command stated above. The trouble I'm facing is declaring and integrating the is.na() command. I'm happy to further explain my problem in case of need.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe `dat$Var3 <- ifelse(!is.na(dat$Var4), NA, dat$Var3)`?

Comment: The code you provide for Stata is not legal syntax.

Comment: I've removed the Stata tag. As the supposed Stata code is no more than pseudocode, the tag is just a distraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```r
df[!is.na(df$Var4),]["Var3"] <- NA

#     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1    a    a <NA>   No
# 2    b    c <NA>  Yes
# 3    a    b  Yes <NA>
# 4    c    a  Yes <NA>
# 5    b    b <NA>  Yes
```

## Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Var3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Var4 = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: You could delete `][` from this

Comment: Thank you,  `df[!is.na(df$Var4),"Var3"] <- NA ` too works.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `replace`

```
df$Var3 <- replace(df$Var3, !is.na(df$Var4), NA)
df

#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#1    a    a <NA>   No
#2    b    c <NA>  Yes
#3    a    b  Yes <NA>
#4    c    a  Yes <NA>
#5    b    b <NA>  Yes
```

If you have `NA` as strings

```
df$Var3 <- replace(df$Var3, df$Var4 != "NA", NA)
```